# APNS Modify Notification to be a Silent Notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a weird feature I'm looking to add to iOS and am not sure if it's possible.

I want to send push notifications to all users through a third party and have the client decide whether or not to show it depending on some feature. I was reading that I can [modify the notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH16-SW1) before it reaches the app and was hoping that I could receive the notification, do some logic and, if the criteria is satisfied, modify the notification to be silent. But I'm not sure if this is possible.

Has anybody been able to do this?

Comment: not possible buddy.. notifications will also be received if the app is not running and you can't really control that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to hide a notification after it was sent. 
You can modify the payload through a service extension but I'm pretty sure you cannot hide it from the user.

To decide on the client if a notification is visible or not - you'll have to send your notification as silent to begin with and then trigger a local notification.
The problems with that are:

- Silent notifications are disabled if the user disabled Background Activity.
- Silent notifications have a lower priority and might be throttled after a while.

The purpose of silent pushes is to inform the app of new content to perform a background fetch.

My recommendation is to put whatever logic you want on the server side before sending the notification.

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can decide whether to show the notification or not.

For iOS, you can only modify the way the notification is presented but you cannot stop it from being shown. In order to modify the way the notification is presented to the user on iOS you need to add a Notification Extension Service.